# Convert SVG paths to KML placemarks?

Tags: javascript, svg, kml

I can find lots of documentation on how to convert KML polygons to SVG objects but nothing to do the reverse. Does such a script exist, or does anyone have any idea of how to write one?

Basically I'd like to take some of the [GPL SVG maps from wikimedia commons](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:SVG_maps) e.g. [this](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Blank_map_europe_coloured.svg), which make individual shapes for each nation/province (and possibly include other geographical overlays), and convert them into KMLs. I'm guessing that a script provided with the coordinate system of the SVG map and the lat/lon of the origin could make this conversion, but this looks like a non-trivial task so I'm hoping something has already been done.

I found the tools at **http://kml2svg.free.fr/**, but this can only convert SVG files that were produced by the KML->SVG converter on the same site.

I also thought that I could maybe reverse the jsfiddle example posted on [convert kml polygons to svg paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13460415/convert-kml-polygons-to-svg-paths), but I've not been able to get the example working in a local web project (I'm pretty new to both SVG/KML development and Javascript, and am unfamiliar with the workings of the Proj.4 library).

Alternatively, if anyone can think of a better approach to solving the original problem of quickly creating "political map" style KML layers I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: First sentence: do you mean you find lots of docs on how to convert KML polys to SVG? or is the question title backwards?

Comment: Oops - that was a typo in the first sentence: the question title is correct. I've fixed the typo now, thanks for spotting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just looking for the same I found your post,
so here's another hit from my google list.

For an initial step, you may want to look at this page:

https://github.com/tbrugz/kmlutils

> The purpose of this project is to provide functions for XML-based "visual" file formats. Main Focus is KML, SVG and GraphML file formats.
>
> The main functionality of this project is a tool for converting SVG files into KML files. Currently it (svg2kml) partially converts polygons (tbrugz.geo.SVG2KML)
>
> This project also provides a conversion tool for SVG to GraphML (tbrugz.geo.SVG2GraphML)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy way to convert SVG paths to SVG polygons in JavaScript. SVG polygons can easily be converted to KML placemarks since both use a list of coordinates. This script can be placed in an HTML file and will directly work off a browser. It will take an SVG file from your computer and save the modified file as a text file. I'd recommend using Chrome, since the SVG maintains a fixed size on it, which ensures that the coordinate system remains exactly the same.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Reader</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>SVG paths to polygons</h1>
<input type="file" id="fileReader" />
<br>
<p id="Content"></p>
<script>
document.getElementById("fileReader").addEventListener('change',function(){
var fr = new FileReader();
fr.onload = function(){;
var d = new DOMParser().parseFromString( this.result.toString(), "image/svg+xml" );
var nodelist = d.querySelectorAll('path');
console.log("Number of paths: " + nodelist.length);
nodelist.forEach(function(path){//This replaces each path with a polygon, keeping the same id.
var polygon = d.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "polygon");
polygon.setAttribute("id", path.getAttribute("id"));
console.log("Converting " + path.getAttribute("id"));
var length = path.getTotalLength();
var p=path.getPointAtLength(0);
var stp=p.x+","+p.y;
for(var i=1; i<length; i++){
    p=path.getPointAtLength(i);
    stp=stp+" "+p.x+","+p.y;
    //This places points along the path at one unit distance apart.
}
polygon.setAttribute("points", stp);
path.replaceWith(polygon);
});
var text1 = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(d);
document.write(text1);
function download(filename, text) {
  var element = document.createElement('a');
  element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
  element.setAttribute('download', filename);

  element.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(element);

  element.click();

  document.body.removeChild(element);
}

// Starting file download.
download("output.txt", text1);
}
fr.readAsText(this.files[0]);
})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can then directly take the `points` attribute and place it in the coordinates tag in a KML placemark. You'll just have to replace the spaces with new lines. While this is not very efficient, it is the simplest way to do the convresion.